# How should you negotiate for a 2.5% raise in salary?

Tags: salary, negotiation

How should you negotiate for a 2.5% raise in salary? Is it reasonable to ask for a 2.5% raise after a year if you didn't get fired and the company has a big turnover issue? How do you negotiate this, and should you quit your job if you don't get 2.5%? I am thinking of asking 5% and then negotiate to get at least 2.5%. My coworkers seem to think I am doing well, but not my direct manager who hates me.

Comment: Yes, I think. Not at all.

Comment: Should you just leave then?

Comment: Does your direct manager hate everybody? Is he the only one to determine your raise?

Comment: Is your salary already adjusted following cost of life? I've worked for companies where such a 2,5% raise was automatic for that reason. I consider having to negociate hard to get it, some kind of a red flag.

Answer (score 2):

(1) FWIW in answer to your question, forget percentages and state **numbers**. Never mention or deal in percentages.

If you're struggling with the language to use, here's an email to copy and paste

So to your direct manager and the greater manager.

> Dear Steve and Bill. Thanks for the great year. Now that twelve months have passed, I'd like to look at a salary of $55xxx rather than my current $50xxx. Due to my performance and loyalty. This would be from the beginning February 15 pay period.  Could you give me your thoughts on this.

Note that it is **utterly pointless going in to details or reasons**. Company's entire raison d'etre is to get work done as cheaply as possible; they don't care about your reasons or thinking on the issue. Any "argument back and fore" is utterly empty and meaningless, platitudes.

Also note that you **MUST** be absolutely explicit about the date and the exact amount to the penny.

If they return with some nonsense like ".. could offer you 1.155%" just reply

> I do feel $55xxx would be appropriate from Feb 15. Could you give me your thoughts on that figure.

(2) You have essentially explained that your job sucks. If so, look for another job. (Allow a concrete and specific 60 minutes a day of your own time to apply to this effort.) Once you secure a firm offer elsewhere, politely leave this company and never think about it again. Note that there are numerous QA on this site about "how to politely leave a position"

You mention your boss "hates" you. It's not high school. I couldn't even *tell you the name* of my current "boss". Do your job, take the money, commute home and live your actual life with family and friends. Be perfectly polite and professional when communicating with the boss in question.

Other than that, think no more about the "boss" than you think about Tasmania.

It's that simple.  Good luck.